# Python: pandas dataframe: Remove " ï»¿ " BOM character

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, utf-8

I used Scrapy on a Linux machine to crawl some websites and saved in a CSV. When I retrieve the dataset and view on a Windows machine, I saw these characters `ï»¿`. Here is what I do to re-encode them to `UTF-8-SIG`:

```
import pandas as pd

my_data = pd.read_csv("./dataset/my_data.csv")
output = "./dataset/my_data_converted.csv"
my_data.to_csv(output, encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False)
```

So now they become `?` if viewed on VSCode. But if I view on Notepad++, I don't see these. How do I actually remove them all?

Comment: Use 'utf-8-sig' when you read the CSV file in Pandas. When you write the file, use 'utf-8'; this will omit the BOM. Without the BOM, however, some Windows programs might not interpret the text correctly and show you gibberish.

Comment: @lenz opening with `utf-8-sig` and then write with `utf-8-sig` again solve the issue. Special characters (in other languages) are retained correctly too. Please post your answer and I'll mark it correct :) Thank you

Comment: @hydradon _opening with utf-8-sig and then write with utf-8-sig again solve the issue._ What happens if you write with just `'utf-8'`, like they suggested?

Comment: The three displayed characters come from the program not understanding UTF-8, it has nothing to do with Windows. In generaly, you don't need to worry about that, unless you're trying to edit the text with that program. Just use a different editor or, if possible, tell the program that it's UTF-8 actually.

Comment: @AMC if I write with `utf-8`, the special characters (like Chinese char) become gibberish.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt in my data, one of the columns contains some link, and I have another python script to access that link. So I just want to make sure that the second script can read the link correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given your comment, I suppose that you ended up having *two* BOMs.

Let's look at a small example.
I'm using built-in `open` instead of `pd.read_csv`/`pd.to_csv`, but the meaning of the `encoding` parameter is the same.

Let's create a file saved as UTF-8 with a BOM:

```
>>> text = 'foo'
>>> with open('/tmp/foo', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
...     f.write(text)
```

Now let's read it back in.
But we use a different encoding: "utf-8" instead of "utf-8-sig".
In your case, you didn't specify the encoding parameter at all, but the default value is most probably "utf-8" or "cp-1252", which both keep the BOM.
So the following is more or less equivalent to your code snippet:

```
>>> with open('/tmp/foo', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
...     text = f.read()
... 
>>> text
'\ufefffoo'
>>> with open('/tmp/foo_converted', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
...     f.write(text)
```

The BOM is read as part of the the text; it's the first character (here represented as `"\ufeff"`).

Let's see what's actually in the files, using a suitable command-line tool:

```sh
$ hexdump -C /tmp/foo
00000000  ef bb bf 66 6f 6f                                 |...foo|
00000006
$ hexdump -C /tmp/foo_converted 
00000000  ef bb bf ef bb bf 66 6f  6f                       |......foo|
00000009
```

In UTF-8, the BOM is encoded as the three bytes `EF BB BF`.
Clearly, the second file has two of them.
So even a BOM-aware program will find some non-sense character in the beginning of *foo_converted*, as the BOM is only stripped once.

Answer (score 0):

For me the BOM was prepended to the first column name. Fortunately Pandas was able to read it into a dataframe, with the BOM still prepended to the first column name. I iterate over ALL columns to remove the BOM from the first column name (since I deal with many different csv files sources, I can't be sure of the first column name):

```
     for column in df.columns: #Need to remove Byte Order Marker at beginning of first column name
        new_column_name = re.sub(r"[^0-9a-zA-Z.,-/_ ]", "", column)
        df.rename(columns={column: new_column_name}, inplace=True)
```

Hope this helps someone..